# JavaScript - passing external html id into event listener

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener

I'm currently learning about event listener by setting up a simple calculator - taking in 2 inputs, clicking the button will print out the calculated action. The code is as follows

HTML

```
<div>
    <input id="num1" type="text" value="1" style="width: 70px">
    <input id="num2" type="text" value="2" style="width: 70px"> 
</div>
<div>
    <button class="calcButton" id="plusBtn" >Plus</button> <br>
    <button class="calcButton" id="mulBtn">Multiply</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
function getPlus(num1, num2) {
    console.log(num1 + num2);
}

function getMul(num1, num2) {
    console.log(num1 * num2);
}

function calc(num1, num2, func) {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.querySelector(num1).value),
        n2 = parseInt(document.querySelector(num2).value);

    func(num1, num2);
}

function actionCall(num1, num2, func) {
    if (func === 'getPlus')
        calc(num1, num2, getPlus);
    else
        calc(num1, num2, getMul);
}

//add event listener to buttons 
document.querySelectorAll('.calcButton').forEach( ele => {
    ele.addEventListener('click', () => {
        actionCall(this.id);
    });
});
```

While I do know how to differentiate the calculation action inside the event listener based on the button id (plus, multiply, etc.). I couldn't find out how to pass the two ids "num1" and "num2" inside it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` takes `css` selector string. you can pass `"#num1"` and `"#num2"` (like you select them in css) to your function.

```js
function getPlus(num1, num2) {
    console.log(num1 + num2);
}

function getMul(num1, num2) {
    console.log(num1 * num2);
}

function calc(num1, num2, func) {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.querySelector(num1).value),
        n2 = parseInt(document.querySelector(num2).value);

    func(n1, n2); //  edited here. get the value from inputs and pass them to func.
}

function actionCall(num1, num2, func) {
    if (func === 'getPlus')
        calc(num1, num2, getPlus);
    else
        calc(num1, num2, getMul);
}

//add event listener to buttons 
document.querySelectorAll('.calcButton').forEach( ele => {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function() { //  edited here. using normal function instead of arrow function so that we can use "this" keyword.
        actionCall("#num1", "#num2", this.id); //  edited here. passing the inputs' id and the button's id.
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="num1" type="text" value="1" style="width: 70px">
    <input id="num2" type="text" value="2" style="width: 70px"> 
</div>
<div>
    <button class="calcButton" id="getPlus" >Plus</button> <br> <!--  edited here. changed id to match the function name. -->
    <button class="calcButton" id="getMul">Multiply</button> <!--  edited here. changed id to match the function name. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I wonder if there is any way not to directly use the id inside the js (e.g., "#num1") tho. Just curious to improve flexibility

Comment: can you give me an example of the flexibility you talking about?

Comment: The `func` parameter for the method `actionCall` was defined by the variable `this.id` rather than explicitly `#getPlus` (or `#getMul`). Is there any way to do the same with (`#num1` and `#num2`)?

Comment: i'm starting get what you mean. if you want pass inputs' id from html to js without hard code the ids inside js (ex: `"#num1"`), you can make use of [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) attribute. on your button, define dataset like `<button class="calcButton" id="getPlus" data-num1="#num1" data-num2="#num2">Plus</button>`. and inside add event listener function `actionCall(this.dataset.num1, this.dataset.num2, this.id);`.